# Change order user tabs through div elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-3, dom

Below is the code I'm using in my ASP MVC view. I'd like the tab order to go from the first to last text box inputs in the fieldsets below in this order:

1. AgentTypeFields
2. BasicFields
3. AddressFields
4. CommunicationFields
5. DistributionFields
6. DRMFields
7. DSSAgentIds
8. DSSFields

Right now when the focus of the page is on the first input box of `AgentTypeFields`, which is the fieldset in the `leftDiv` of the `topDiv`. When the user is done tabbing through this fieldset, the focus then shifts to the first input of `DistributionFields`. Basically I need the tab index to move from the `leftDiv` fieldsets going from the `topDiv`, `middleDiv`, to the `bottomDiv`, and then back up through the `rightDiv` elements of the same top/middle/bottom `divs`.

I've tried puttint a `tabindex` property on the `div` and `fieldset` elements but this simply puts the focus on the element itself, not the inputs contained within it. Not the greatest when it comes to HTML/CSS so any suggests/help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<div id="BigDiv" style="clear:both;">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreatedDate)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreatedOperator)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReferenceNumber)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReferenceType)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ExtRepType) 
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Region)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.INDDist)
    <div id="topDiv">
        <div class="LeftDiv" style="width: 450px; float:left;">
            <fieldset id="AgentTypeFields" style="width: 400px;">...</fieldset>
        </div> 
        <div class="RightDiv" style="width: 450px; float:left;">
            <fieldset id="DistributionFields" style="width: 400px;">...</fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="middleDiv">
        <div class="LeftDiv" style="width: 450px; float:left;">
            <fieldset id="BasicFields" style="width: 400px;">...</fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="RightDiv" style="width: 450px; float:left;">
            <fieldset id="DRMFields" style="width: 400px;">...</fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottomDiv">
        <div class="LeftDiv" style="width: 450px; float:left;">
            <fieldset id="AddressFields" style="width: 400px;">...</fieldset>

            <fieldset id="CommunicationFields" style="width: 400px;">...</fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="RightDiv" style="width: 450px; float:left;">
            <fieldset id="DSSAgentIds" style="width: 400px;">...</fieldset>

            <fieldset id="DSSFields" style="width: 400px;">...</fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to Search", "Index", "Agent")  
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the tabindex on the first field in those fieldsets rather than the fieldset itself. However, this is really going to screw with the blind individuals who come to your site.

Comment: Because that's not how tabindex works. If you specify it at all then you are now in total control of the tab order. Anything you don't give a tabindex to, won't be able to be navigated to via tab. You need to number *all* the fields in the order you want them.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say was basically that. It goes from the item with a tab index of 1, to a tab index of 2 and skips everything in between. Is there a way to do this, then, without giving every single input field a tab index?

Comment: No. That's how it works. If you specify tabindex 1 and 2 then it will go directly from 1 to 2; it doesn't care what's inbetween, you literally told it that the next thing it should tab to should be the one with 2.